# How to concatenate two strings in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a private class variable `char name[10]` to which I would like to add the `.txt` extension so that I can open the file present in the directory.

How do I go about this?

It would be preferable to create a new string variable that holds the concatenated string.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

First of all, don't use `char*` or `char[N]`. Use `std::string`, then everything else becomes so easy!

Examples,

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::string greet = s + " World"; //concatenation easy!
```

Easy, isn't it?

Now if you need `char const *` for some reason, such as when you want to pass to some function, then you can do this:

```
some_c_api(s.c_str(), s.size());
```

assuming this function is declared as:

```
some_c_api(char const *input, size_t length);
```

Explore `std::string` yourself starting from here:

- [Documentation of std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: What is the time complexity of this string concatenation ?

Comment: @d34th4ck3r: It is linear.

Comment: Becomes easy at the cost of memory and performance. Don't overuse strings!

Comment: @EpicSpeedy: You're going to be hard-pressed to concatenate O(n) characters in less than O(n) time !

Answer (score 40):

Since it's C++ why not to use `std::string` instead of `char*`?
Concatenation will be trivial:

```
std::string str = "abc";
str += "another";
```

Comment: Worth noting, the trivial use comes with a non-trivial price tag with respect to runtime performance. Worst case is, that `operator+=` performs both a deallocation and an allocation. Heap allocations are among the most expensive operations we commonly do.

Answer (score 23):

If you were programming in C, then assuming `name` really is a fixed-length array like you say, you have to do something like the following:

```
char filename[sizeof(name) + 4];
strcpy (filename, name) ;
strcat (filename, ".txt") ;
FILE* fp = fopen (filename,...
```

You see now why everybody recommends `std::string`?

Comment: Don't you think this answer is irrelevant for this question?

Comment: I do think this is relevant since "the guy" is using char instead of std::string. Furthermore, it shows an explicit way of concatenating that was not showed in the most voted answer. At least I learned something with it.

Comment: This also shows a method of doing a string concatenation without dynamic memory allocation.  Unless I am wrong, std::string operator += requires a possible reallocation.

Comment: As of 9th March 2023, this answer is *absolutely* relevant.  Thanks @TonyK!  (I am working on an old project that primarily uses C.)

Answer (score 8):

There is a [strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) function from the ported C library that will do "C style string" concatenation for you.

BTW even though C++ has a bunch of functions to deal with C-style strings, it could be beneficial for you do try and come up with your own function that does that, something like:

```
char * con(const char * first, const char * second) {
    int l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
    const char * f = first, * l = second;

    // find lengths (you can also use strlen)
    while (*f++) ++l1;
    while (*l++) ++l2;

    // allocate a buffer including terminating null char
    char *result = new char[l1 + l2 + 1];

    // then concatenate
    for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++) result[i] = first[i];
    for (int i = l1; i < l1 + l2; i++) result[i] = second[i - l1];

    // finally, "cap" result with terminating null char
    result[l1 + l2] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

...and then...

```
char s1[] = "file_name";
char *c = con(s1, ".txt");
```

... the result of which is `file_name.txt`.

You might also be tempted to write your own `operator +` however IIRC operator overloads with only pointers as arguments is not allowed.

Also, don't forget the result in this case is dynamically allocated, so you might want to call delete on it to avoid memory leaks, or you could modify the function to use stack allocated character array, provided of course it has sufficient length.

Comment: See my comment to IcyFlame's answer.

Comment: There is also `strncat()` function that is usually better alternative

Comment: @nogard: `strncat` is irrelevant here, because we already know the length of the second parameter `".txt"`. So it would just be `strncat(name, ".txt", 4)`, which doesn't gain us anything.

Answer (score 4):

C++14

```
std::string great = "Hello"s + " World"; // concatenation easy!
```

Answer on the question:

```
auto fname = ""s + name + ".txt";
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the 's' at the end for making a literal sting into an object-type string. This is quite handy! Reminds me of python too.

Comment: but only if you declare `using namespace std::string_literals;`

Comment: @masher I get `error std has no member string_literals`

Comment: @johnktejik Remember to ensure that you're compiling the source according to C++14.

Answer (score 0):

strcat(destination,source) can be used to concatenate two strings in c++.

To have a deep understanding you can lookup in the following link-

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use C++ string class instead of old style C string, life would be much easier.

if you have existing old style string, you can covert to string class

```
    char greeting[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    cout<<greeting + "and there \n"; //will not compile because concat does \n not work on old C style string
    string trueString = string (greeting);
    cout << trueString + "and there \n"; // compiles fine
    cout << trueString + 'c'; // this will be fine too. if one of the operand if C++ string, this will work too
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//String appending
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void stringconcat(char *str1, char *str2){
    while (*str1 != '\0'){
        str1++;
    }

    while(*str2 != '\0'){
        *str1 = *str2;
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str1[100];
    cin.getline(str1, 100);  
    char str2[100];
    cin.getline(str2, 100);

    stringconcat(str1, str2);

    cout<<str1;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [std::strcat()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat)?