# How to concat char array into a string

Tags: c++, c++98, visual-studio-6

Below I have two variable store in a char array

```
char one[7]  = "130319";
char two[7] =  "05A501";
```

I try to concat them with stringstream

```
std::ostringstream sz;
sz << one<< two;
```

After that I convert it to string

```
std::string stringh = sz.str();
```

Then I try to merge it to form  the path of a file
and write text in that file

```
std::string start="d:/testingwinnet/json/";
std::string end= ".json";
std::string concat= start+stringh + end;

ofstream myfile(concat);

myfile << "test";
myfile.close();
```

And I am getting the following error

> ```
> error C2040: 'str' : 'class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' differs in levels
> of indirection from 'char *
> ```

Any idea. Many thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on g++: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5258e846a9d78fb3. What compiler are you using, and could it be out of date?

Comment: Microsoft Visual c++ 6.0

Comment: Surely the compiler at least says which line the error is on. I suspect it's `ofstream myfile(concat);` and that the char arrays are irrelevant.

Comment: yes, that is right, any solution to this

Comment: You don't need the string stream of the temporary `stringh` variable. Just do `std::string filename = start + one + two + end;`

Comment: still has this error C2664: '__thiscall std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::std::basic_ofstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(const char *,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::ba
sic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char *'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use a ***very*** old version of Visual Studio. Much much older than the C++11 standard, which introduced the ability to pass `std::string` as filenames to file streams.

You must use a C-style string (`const char *`) as filename when opening files with e.g `std::ofstream`.

So the solution with your current code is to do

```
ofstream myfile(concat.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider checking out this previous answer for string concatenation [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)