# Add a Char array to a Char * variable in c++

Tags: c++

I am makinga code to send a query for my SQLlite database, but I just can't find a way to add a variable to the Char * variable that is being used as the query. the query and the variable that I want to add are declared like this:

```
String p = "10004F1F7";
 char *sql = "SELECT * from TABELTAGGEGEVENS WHERE ID =" + p;
```

the error  i get is this: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'Arp::BasicString' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]

many thanks.

Comment: What's `String`? Why is the `"String p = ` inside the string as well?

Comment: Why do you think *adding* a literal string to an object of whatever `String` is would result in a `char *`?

Comment: what is `Arp::BasicString` ? Did you consult its documentation? Does it have a conversion to a c array of `char`?

Comment: How are you expecting the memory holding this string to be managed? Also, what's a `String` exactly? Is it coming from some library you're using?

Comment: Make sql an std::string, and add the two strings with std::string's operator+

If, for some reason, you need to pass sql as a char*, use std::string's c_str(). Note it returns a const char*, if you need a non-const pointer, check whether the function actually changes the string, in which case you'll have to copy it to a char array, otherwise you could const_cast (ugly as it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because in C++ the '+' operator on char pointers doesn't concatenate the strings.
One solution would be to make the literal value a String as well:

```
String p = "10004F1F7";
String query = "SELECT * from TABELTAGGEGEVENS WHERE ID =";
```

You can then concatenate like this: `+` operator: `p + operator`

I don't know the particular library you appear to be working with (`Arp::BasicString`), so I don't know how you'd convert that into a char *.

With std::string you can simply call `c_str` on the result.

Another and probably better solution is to use formatters.

For reference see:

- https://www.thecodingdelight.com/string-cplusplus/
- [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/text/string-and-i-o-formatting-modern-cpp?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

```
String p = "10004F1F7";
char *sql = "SELECT * from TABELTAGGEGEVENS WHERE ID =" + p;
```

You can handle the `Arp::BasicString`  almost like an `std::string.`

Looking through the headers you will find a Method named `"CStr()"`.

Like that you should be able to do something like this:

```
String P = "10004F1F7";
String Query = "SELECT * from TABELTAGGEGEVENS WHERE ID =" + p;
char *sql = Query.CStr()
```

Comment: This is even better than the accepted answer, because it gives a simple explanation for how to convert the resulting string to `char *`

Answer (score 0):

The only hit on Google for `Arp::BasicString` was used in the SDK for a software company, PLCnext. A little bit of riffling through I found a header file `BasicString.hxx` and inside a prototype for `BasicString` class template. There the `baseString` data structure is private.

I had to come up with this (rather low-level) workaround, compiling with PLCnext software succeeded and passed tests when adjusted for `std::string`):

```
String p = "10004F1F7";
const char* CMD_SEQUENCE = "SELECT * from TABELTAGGEGEVENS WHERE ID =";
const int CMD_LENGTH = 41;

// allocate and assign memory for the static characters in the command
char *sql = (char *)malloc(CMD_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
memcpy(sql, CMD_SEQUENCE, CMD_LENGTH);

// iterate through all chars in String p
// resizing the memory buffer as needed and adding ith char to the end
for (int i=0; i<p.Size();i++){

    sql = (char*)realloc(sql, (CMD_LENGTH + i) * sizeof(char));

    // destination is the ith memory cell past the cmd sequence
    int destIdx = CMD_LENGTH + i;

    // copy 1 char at a time; ith char in p
    memcpy( &sql[destIdx], &p.At(i), sizeof(char) );
}
```