# Set console size in characters

Tags: c++, console

I want to be able to set the console size to be exacly the same no matter what device it runs on, so far I have used

```
static const int nScreenWidth = 80;
static const int nScreenHeight = 30;
int main()
{
    system("MODE CON COLS=80 LINES=30");
}
```

But since I`m storing the width and height in variables it needs to be changed manually and that is not cool.
I have tried

```
system("MODE CON COLS=" + std::to_string(nScreenWidth).c_str() + " LINES=30");
```

but I get expression must have integral or unscoped enum type.

All of the functions from

```
#include <windows.h>
```

set the console size in pixels but I need it to be in characters.

Comment: `"MODE CON COLS=" + std::to_string(nScreenWidth).c_str() + " LINES=30"` do all that with the `std::string` first. Here your problem is you are trying to append 3 c-strings

Comment: Works wonderful, out of curiosity why can`t you add 3 c-strings together?

Comment: They are dumb and don't support operator+() remember these are from `c`. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: C-strings are just char arrays or pointers to the first element of char arrays. There's no `+` operator overloaded for char arrays or char pointers.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
std::string str = "MODE CON COLS=" + std::to_string(nScreenWidth) + " LINES=30";

system(str.c_str());
```

Comment: I think you have 2 bugs with your first line. [https://ideone.com/8F0ZDl](https://ideone.com/8F0ZDl)