# Why rename() function not working when I cut strings?

Tags: c++, rename, fstream

I am working With files. Currently I am sequentially renaming some files I know a little about fstream. I simply want to rename multiple file sequentially with loop.Why this code is not working? Is there any another way to do? i just want to done my job. Thank you for reading <3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// not working
for(int i=1;i<=20;i++;){
 
 rename(("oldname"+to_string(i)+"txt"),((newname+to_string(i)+"txt"));



}
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Why this code is not working?* -- What do you mean by "not working"?  What error(s) are you receiving?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::rename` takes two parameters of type `const char *`. But the result of string concatenation is `std::string`. You can use `.c_str()` to access to underlying C-style-string like so:

```
auto oldFileName = "oldname" + to_string(i) + "txt";
auto newFileName = newname + to_string(i) + "txt";

rename(oldFileName.c_str(), newFileName.c_str());
```

**But it can get easier than this:** `rename` is a relic from C. In C++ you should use [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) (if you can use C++17). One advantage is, that in can work with `std::string`.