# Is there any way to tell C++11 to use std::string instead of const char*?

Tags: c++, c++11

Im trying to migrate code from another language that allows concatonation of strings with the '+' operator.

```
//defintion 
void print(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s;
}
//call
print("Foo " + "Bar");
```

The issue I'm having is that c++ sees "Foo " and "Bar" as const char* and cannot add them, is there any way to fix this. I have tried including the string library to see if it would change them automatically but that didnt seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: not an answer, but do pass strings between functions as `const std::string& s` instead of as `std::string s`.  Avoids a copy and enables opitimizations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and later:

```
using namespace std::literals;
print("Foo "s + "Bar");
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```
std::string operator "" _s(const char* str, std::size_t len) {
    return std::string(str, len);
}

print("Foo "_s + "Bar");
```

Or, in all versions:

```
print(std::string("Foo ") + "Bar");
```

Comment: This is a good solution in general, but as the OP said in comment: "*I forgot to mention that I was in c++11*", so this won't work for the OP specifically.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution for the case of 2 string literals:

```
print("Foo " "Bar");
```

Otherwise:

```
print(std::string("Foo ") + "Bar");
```