# Why can't I display chars properly in C++ WinForms Message Box?

Tags: c++, winforms, clr

So I'm having trouble concatenating strings and chars and then displaying them using the message box because my characters get printed as numbers, and when I try to convert them to string no matter where or how the message box throws an error! Any help is appreciated!

```
MessageBox::Show("The most common letter is \"" + letters[biggetsNumberIndex] + "\".");
// Simplified version: MessageBox::Show("string" + 'c' + "string");
```

Comment: [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Comment: It's the character that causes problems. I can concatenate them just fine, but the characters get displayed as numbers.

Comment: Have you defined the array as, e.g., `array<Char>^ arr = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };`? In this case, `MessageBox::Show("Last char is the " + arr[2] + " letter");` will show `Last char is the c letter`

Comment: It would be the same in case `letters` is `String^ letters = "abc";`

Comment: I just used char letters[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}, But also tried using simple std::string letters = "abc"

Comment: I highly recommend building the string before calling `Show()`.  This allows you to place a breaking at `Show()` and see the string contents.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it thanks to "Jimi" I changed the "letters" variable instead of character array or std::string I used String^

```
// Bad
std::string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

// Good
String^ letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Comment: It's not *bad*, it's just *unmanaged*. You could have `const char* letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`, which could be *transformed* as `String^ lLetters = gcnew String(letters);` and `MessageBox::Show(L"string " + lLetters[2] + L" string");` -- With `std::string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`, you can marshal as `String^ lLetters = marshal_as<String^>(letters);` <- careful here since you can mess up some macros if you handle COM objects, as (quite common) `IDataObject`s, when you `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>`

Comment: Yes, I know it's not bad it's just to make it clear. Anyway, it was the simplest solution. Thanks for the info.