# How do I return a string with variables and characters in c++?

Tags: c++, string, function, return, cout

I have a string function that I would like to output the following cout lines.

```
 string print_ticket(void){
        if(sold_status == true){
            cout<<seat_number<<" "<<seat_number<<"sold";
        }
        else{
            cout<<seat_number<<" "<<seat_number<<"available";
        }
    }
```

The problem is the function must return a string and I'm not sure the best way to turn these cout statement into a string in this scenario.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate two strings in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319859/how-to-concatenate-two-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ostringstream`, available when including `<sstream>`:

```cpp
string print_ticket(void){
    std::ostringstream sout;
    if (sold_status) {
        sout << seat_number << " " << seat_number << "sold";
    }
    else {
        sout << seat_number << " " << seat_number << "available";
    }
    return sout.str();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Derek's answer can be simplified somewhat.  Plain old strings can be concatenated (and also chained), so you can reduce it to:

```
string print_ticket(void){
    string seat_number_twice = seat_number + " " + seat_number + " ";  // seems a bit weird, but hey
    if (sold_status)
        return seat_number_twice + "sold"; 
    return seat_number_twice + "available"; 
}
```

Which is more efficient?  Well, it depends.